# Grabbing Data From Workbook With Compiler Error

Tags: excel, vba

Compiler Error: End With Has No With. I know that this is wrong, and there is something in my code in where I am not calling it correctly that is making it mess up but I cannot find it. I'm just trying to grab information off of my sheet1 so that I can use it later on.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    While (Counter <= 300) 
            Pcounter = .Cells(ACBoxCounter, 2)
        If (Pcounter <> "") Then
            ACounter = ACounter + 1
        End If
            ACBCounter = ACBCounter + 30
    Wend

    While (OverallACounter < ACounter)
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    objStream.Open


    ExampleString = .Cells(Row2Counter + 22, 3)
    ChooseM = Split(ExampleString, "-")(1)
    If (ChooseM = "8") 
      M = "II"
      P = 97
      Label = .Cells(Row2Counter, 2)
    ElseIf (ChooseM = "13") Then
      Model = "A II"
      P = 10
      Label = "A6_" & .Cells(Row2Counter, 2)
    ElseIf (ChooseM = "19") Then
      M = "AC1I"
      P = 56
      Label = "A9_" & .Cells(Row2Counter, 2)
    End If
    OverallD = 0
    Overall= 0
    OverallB = 0
    ChooseBoxType = Split(ExampleString, "-")(2)
    If ((StrComp(ChooseB, "1") = 0) Or (StrComp(ChooseB, "1M") = 0)) Then
      BoxInputT= "1 Phase"
    ElseIf ((StrComp(ChooseB, "2") = 0) Or (StrComp(ChooseB, "2M") = 0))  Then
      BoxInput= "2"
    ElseIf ((StrComp(ChooseB ,"3") = 0) Or (StrComp(ChooseBo, "3M") = 0)) Then
      BoxInput= "3"
    End If
 objStream.WriteText ("  <" & .Cells(Row2Counter, 2).Text & ">" & vbLf)
Wend
End With
```

Compiler Error: End With Has No With

Comment: Proper [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) would show you you're missing a `Wend` for the second `While` loop.

Comment: I messed up and forgot to copy that over originally. That is there in my code, am I calling the data correctly with .cells?

Comment: You're also missing a `Then` in `If (ChooseM = "8")`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your help! I just kept skipping over it.

Comment: Like @BigBen said, proper indentation will help reduce those kind of issues just like `Option Explicit` will help with other issues

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to vba and I usually indent after I finish the code, I guess that I should get into the habit of indenting as I go so that I don't have to worry about it at the end.